# Getting my object to push multiple arrays based on id

Tags: database, vue.js

I'm using vue and the issue I'm having is that when I try to push to an object I'm not getting the array I'm expecting.

I have multiple rows and each row has an ID based on what comes from the database and when I edit that row I need to emit to my parent vue container all the values I need, so far this has been ok.

The issue comes in, is when I try to create an object that will give me an output like this

```
30: 0: {field: name, value: 'rob'}
    1: {field: address, value: '12 randomstreet'}
```

but instead what I am getting is that what ever new value I enter it overwrites the object.

This is the code

```
editRole(payload){
    console.log('editRole(role)', payload);

    let savingChangesObj = {};

    savingChangesObj[payload.id] = {
        field: payload.field,
        value: payload.value
    };

    console.log(savingChangesObj);
},
```

Comment: It does not overwrite the object. But you redeclare the object making it empty every time. Using vue you should probably declare it at data().

Comment: @Wimanicesir - thank you so much. I didn't even realize that I was doing that